# Talend Component "OracleInput" don't find datas

Tags: sql, oracle, mongodb, talend

I have a problem on Talend Open Studio for Big Data, for a  project i ahve to import in MongoDB datas which come from an Oracle Database.
The problem is my connection to Oracle is correct, but with some table the "component" OracleInput" don't find datas on it.
Here is a screenshot which i think will help you to understand.

Half of my table work but the other half can't find datas.
Of course, those tables are all full of datas in Oracle Database, and the SQL Query are functionnal for all the componants.

Sorry for my broken English, i'm still learning.

Thanks for all your futur help !

Comment: Please look over the instructions on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can't find any screenshot. can you add one for te whole job and one for the not working tOracleInput component?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the screenshot and the SQL code from the `tOracleInput` component.

Comment: Does your schema in the talend component contains all the columns?